# Dropdown list in Flows shows truncated list of choices

Tags: apex, flow, process-builder

I have a Task Flow called Shop Call that allows reps to enter Call details as a Task. 
I have 1 field that allows the rep to select from a list of Bioriginal Contacts (there are 155 Contacts associated to the main Bioriginal Account). The # of Choices is limited to 200 choice according to the Help & Training documentation.

However, when I run through the flow, it does not display all 155 Contact names - it shows probably less than half of the 155. Why doesn't the dropdown list show all 155 choices? These choices are created using a Dynamic Record Choice

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're picking up on one of the flaws with Dynamic Record Choice... it can return just too many values!  I would suggest that you add in a second screen, that allows the user to filter by a name, and your Dynamic Record Choice using the Contains on that field so that you can look to limit the outcomes.  155 is a ton of values to scroll through... If I was the End User I don't think I would mind at all to have an extra screen to stop scrolling through 100+ options til I find the one I want.